# Samba 4 gives "Failed to find a writeable DC for domain" on samba-tool domain join

Tags: centos, samba, active-directory

I have a CentOS 6.4 box with SerNet's Samba 4.0.8 installed and [no smb.conf file yet, as it should be](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4/HOWTO/Join_a_domain_as_a_DC#Getting_ready_for_joining_Samba_as_a_DC_to_an_existing_domain).  I want it to become an AD DC in my existing Windows domain, replicating from the existing Windows Server 2003 box.  I have SELinux enabled and want it to stay that way in the end, but would be willing to attempt to disable it temporarily.  But I've [run `sudo setsebool -P samba_domain_controller on` and `sudo setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs on`](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetUpSamba#head-86233024cba06a1e4f554e763a2f634a61eae9b8) and they returned no errors.

Also I opted to try using Samba 4's internal DNS rather than BIND.

I'm getting this error trying to run samba-tool:

```
$ sudo samba-tool domain join currentwindowsadserver.mydomain.lan DC -Uadministrator --realm=currentwindowsadserver.mydomain.lan
Finding a writeable DC for domain 'currentwindowsadserver.mydomain.lan'
ERROR(exception): uncaught exception - Failed to find a writeable DC for domain 'currentwindowsadserver.mydomain.lan'
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 175, in _run
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/samba/netcmd/domain.py", line 552, in run
    machinepass=machinepass, use_ntvfs=use_ntvfs, dns_backend=dns_backend)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/samba/join.py", line 1082, in join_DC
    machinepass, use_ntvfs, dns_backend, promote_existing)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/samba/join.py", line 73, in __init__
    ctx.server = ctx.find_dc(domain)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/samba/join.py", line 246, in find_dc
    raise Exception("Failed to find a writeable DC for domain '%s'" % domain)
```

Same situation as described [here](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/IPyW4ncMVDjCSvPSCGDx), but the suggested `-S` does not seem to exist anymore--it spits out usage directions when I try it and said:

```
samba-tool domain join: error: no such option: -S
```

I tried [adding the old and new to `/etc/hosts`](http://forum.zentyal.org/index.php/topic,12035.15.html) but that didn't change the results.

`kinit` and `klist` work as they should, and `host -t A mynewserver` also produces correct output (giving the correct IP and the correct name, see below.)

Currently, my windows AD server has 5 names and 5 IP addresses, but if I ping it from CentOS by its main name that I use for everything Windows (the other 4 I only use for Apache, yes I know, running Apache on Windows...you can see why I'm migrating) it returns correctly as that name.  Nonetheless I thought maybe that was causing some problems, so seeing [this page](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/samba-tool.8.html) (and even `samba-tool domain join -h`) I also tried adding `--ipaddress=192.168.1.2` and it said that it wasn't a valid option either:

```
samba-tool domain join: error: no such option: --ip-address
```

`samba-tool domain info` without `DC` but otherwise the same parameters as at the start, correctly gives me info about the Windows DC.  Also DNS seems to be fine:

```
$ host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.mydomain.lan
_ldap._tcp.mydomain.lan has SRV record 0 100 389 currentwindowsadserver.mydomain.lan
$ host -t SRV _kerberos._udp.mydomain.lan
_kerberos._udp.mydomain.lan has SRV record 0 100 88 currentwindowsadserver.mydomain.lan
$ host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.mydomain.lan
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.mydomain.lan has SRV record 0 100 389 currentwindowsadserver.mydomain.lan
$ host -t SRV _kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs.mydomain.lan
_kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs.mydomain.lan has SRV record 0 100 88 currentwindowsadserver.mydomain.lan
$ host -t SRV _kpasswd._tcp.mydomain.lan
_kpasswd._tcp.mydomain.lan has SRV record 0 100 464 currentwindowsadserver.mydomain.lan.
$ host -t SRV _kpasswd._udp.mydomain.lan
_kpasswd._udp.mydomain.lan has SRV record 0 100 464 currentwindowsadserver.mydomain.lan.
$ host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.gc._msdcs.mydomain.lan
_ldap._tcp.gc._msdcs.mydomain.lan has SRV record 0 100 3268 currentwindowsadserver.mydomain.lan.
$ host -t SRV _gc._tcp.mydomain.lan
_gc._tcp.mydomain.lan has SRV record 0 100 3268 currentwindowsadserver.mydomain.lan.
```

ATM, AFAIK, we're an IPv4-only network (one page mentioned IPv6 issues).  I don't see any IPv6 addresses when I ping or run `host -t A` or anything like that--if this is the issue I'm not sure what to do to verify or fix it, maybe someone could help me out with that.

`sudo netstat -tunpe | grep ":53"` returns nothing, and I have [iptables open on 445 UDP and TCP](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetUpSamba#head-26340a1a2c9cb4d46d51b9429fd030239b57feb4).  Update, I now have it open on [everything listed here](http://www.alexwyn.com/computer-tips/centos-samba4-active-directory-domain-controller) except the NetBIOS ones, and reloaded iptables without error, but still no change.  I've also tried stopping the iptables service temporarily, no difference.

I also have both `domain` and `search` directives with mydomain.lan after them in `/etc/resolv.conf`, as well as `nameserver` with the primary IP of the Windows box.

What else could it be?  Google isn't giving me much else to try here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was passing the wrong info to samba-tool.  `currentwindowsadserver` is the dc, not the domain or realm.  Instead of:

```
sudo samba-tool domain join currentwindowsadserver.mydomain.lan DC -Uadministrator --realm=currentwindowsadserver.mydomain.lan
```

...the command should simply read:

```
sudo samba-tool domain join mydomain.lan DC -Uadministrator --realm=mydomain.lan
```

This succeeded, with SELinux still enabled, and with the `domain` directive in resolv.conf commented out.